# Meteor: rerender Template with reactive data on browser event

Tags: meteor, coffeescript

I have the following router and template defined. However when the event handler is called the template is not being rerendered. I was under the impression that the items cursor was reactive; how should the event handler update this variable?

```js
MyRouter = RouteController.extend
template: 'myTemplate'
subscriptions: Meteor.subscribe 'items'
items: Items.find {}
data: ->
    items: @items()

Template.myTemplate.events
'click .someButton': (e) ->
    Template.parentData().items = Items.find({ .. })
```

```html
          <!-- parent template -->  
          {{#each ../items}}
              <div class='radio'>
                <label>
                  <input type='radio' name='optionsRadios' id='{{this.id}}' value='{{this.id}}'>
                  {{this.text}}
                </label>
              </div>
            {{/each}}
```

Comment: Pass on template events the tpl instance ```'click .someButton': (e, tpl) ->``` and look for your data there in ```console.log(tpl)```, this can help for debug.

Comment: In the handler I am accessing the Template's parent, which is where the 'items' variable is scoped to, and updating it with the new items cursor.

Comment: this would be a lot easier if you save items in a Session onBeforeAction in router controller